# Recording the time into a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to test how long my battery runs on my raspberry pi. All i need to do is run a while loop until the battery dies. However, I need to record the time that it starts and ends. I would like to save the data into a txt file. My current code is as follows:

```
import time

file = open('time','w')

x=1
while x==1:
     from datetime import datetime
     now = datetime.now()

file.write(now)
file.close()
```

If I just print the results in python i will get a result, and the current code makes a file called 'file' but there is nothing saved in the txt file. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time

Comment: You are not recording when it starts, all you are doing is getting the current time. Let me ask another question - if this code is running on the board itself, and you have attached the battery as the power source to the board - when the battery dies wouldn't the board just shutdown? You need to find a way to track when the battery is reaching a low threshold, and then write the time when that occurs.

Comment: _Please_ put import statements at the top of your program, don't bury them in your code. And especially don't put them inside a loop!

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop which just gets the current time over and over again ... This loop won't break (even if your battery dies ...).

At some point, you need to `break` the loop or the condition in the `while` needs to become `False`.  e.g.

```
from datetime import datetime
while x == 1:
    now = datetime.now()
    break
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime
while x == 1:
    now = datetime.now()
    x += 1
```

Generally speaking, you'll want to look in your system logs for when the computer decided to start up and when it decided to shut down due to lack of battery power ...

Comment: Even so, shouldn't the x in this case represent what the battery life is?

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend code that looks like the following:

```
import time
import datetime.datetime as dt 

initTime = dt.now()

while True:
    with open('time.txt', 'a') as f: 
        f.write( str(dt.now() - initTime) )
    time.sleep(1)
```

The couple of differences. First, you always open the file in `append` mode. This way, the file will be flushed every time. Next, it will always update the file with the amount of time elapsed. So even if your raspberry pi shuts down, you should be able to recover it.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections! Will make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

No need to record these times yourself. The Pi (and almost any Linux distribution) writes those events to the `/var/log/wtmp` file (more about that file [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/wtmp)). The `last` command can retrieve those events (also see [the manual entry for last](http://linux.die.net/man/1/last)). Try the following:

```
last -FRx | grep -e 'boot\|shutdown'
```

Explanation of the flags:

- -F prints the full date and times - which is handy in your case, because that's what you wanted to know.
- -R suppresses the hostname in the output. You don't need that.
- -x shows shutdown en runlevel changes - now *that's* what you wanted to know.

Finally the `grep` statement filters out the boot or shutdown messages.